# C# web scraping with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

[I want to create application in WPF wchich will **scrape** information from webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFGhd.png)

[I read link to the page from text box at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq5k0.png)

[I want to extract company name from h6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2E1t.png)

I don't understand that format:"//h2[@class='card__title mdc-typography--headline6']". I could't find documentation abot meaning @ [] etc. to create another filters to **scrape** other data for example phone number from  tag.

Comment: You can either go via CSS Selectors, like Selvin said, or you can use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), which the pack supports. Use whatever suits your needs best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@, //, ...` represent abbreviated syntax for [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) selectors.

> - `@abc` is short for `attribute::abc`
> - `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

So, in other terms, your current query `//h2[@class='card__title mdc-typography--headline6']` represents the action of finding the first descendant- or self-node that has a `class` attribute of `card__title mdc-typography--headline6`.